How to fix dry rot on front door?
What’s the best way to fix my front door? Prior to having gutters installed, this door was wet every rainfall and started dry rotting. The dry rot has slowly progressed over the years, and it’s now affecting the screen door that’s attached. Is it as simple as knocking off that 2x4 that’s attached to the door frame and replacing/painting?
https://imgur.com/a/AEzesaT

FYI, that's not "dry rot". It's just rot, and it's rather wet.

Or maybe How do I go about replacing this rotted wood by an exterior door?

Or How do I fix a rotting door frame?, or How should I go about repairing this door casing?

What @isherwood said - please let us know what gaps remain after you have read the other answers. Replacing rotted wood is straightforward: remove the source of rot, remove rot until there is none, replace with new wood, protect new wood.

And protect older wood not replaced.  I see painting in your near future.
